# Inflate ViewStub to cover entire content view

Tags: android, android-layout, viewstub

I would like to inflate a `ViewStub` to cover the entire content view.

The `ViewStub` is contained in the Activity's `CoordinatorLayout` root view. Additionally, the Activity's layout contains a `Toolbar` set as an `ActionBar` via `.setSupportActionBar()`.

Below is the Activity's layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/subView"
        android:layout="@layout/loading_view"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Currently, the `ViewStub` will inflate to take up only the space under the `Toolbar`. I suspect this may be because the `Toolbar` is set as an `ActionBar`, as mentioned earlier. How can I inflate this `ViewStub` so that it takes up the entire content view?

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve the required result by hiding the `ActionBar` manually, via `getSupportActionBar.hide()`. This lets the inflated layout take up the entire content view.

If anyone knows of a better solution, please submit it.